# Countdown on Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, observable

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {

//----------------------------------------------------------------------LISTAGEM ALMOÇOS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        let data = JSON.stringify({id: this.id});
        let link = *;
        this.http.post(link,data)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data=>{
                console.log(data);
              this.almocos = [];
              //IDs das conversas
              for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++){
                this.foto2 = data[a][2];
                if(Number.isInteger(data[a][7])){
                  console.log(data[a][7])
                  this.tempo[0] = data[a][7] + "dias"
                  this.tempo[1] = "";
                  this.tempo[2] = "";
                }else {
                  this.tempo = data[a][7].split(":");
                  this.tempo[0] = this.tempo[0] + ":";
                  this.tempo[1] = this.tempo[1] + ":"

                }
              
                  
                
                this.tempos = [];
                this.foto =[];
                let cor;
                  let pessoas;
                  let forma;
               if (data[a][4].length == 1){
                 if(data[a][5]== this.nome){
                   data[a][2]= data[a][4][0][1]
                 }
                 pessoas = data[a][4][0][0];
                 this.foto.push(data[a][4][0][1]);
               } else if (data[a][4].length == 2) {
                 pessoas = data[a][4][0][0] + " e " + data[a][4][1][0];
                  this.foto.push(data[a][4][0][1]);
                   this.foto.push(data[a][4][1][1]);
               } else {
                 pessoas = data[a][4][0][0] + " e " + (data[a][4].length-1) + " pessoas"
                  for (var i = 0; i < data[a][4].length; i++){ 
                     this.foto.push(data[a][4][i][1]);
                  }
               }
              

               if(data[a][4].length > 1){
                 if(data[a][6] == 1){
                   data[a][2] = "social.png";
                   cor= "#e73C58";
                   forma = "S"
                 } else if (data[a][6] == 2){
                   data[a][2] = "profissional.png";
                    cor= "#1ab2bc";
                    forma = "P";
                 }else if (data[a][6] == 3){
                   data[a][2] = "academico.png";
                   cor= "#9b59b6";
                   forma = "A";
                 }
               }else{
                 if(data[a][6] == 1){
                    cor= "#e73C58 ";
                    forma = "S"
                  } else if (data[a][6] == 2){
                    cor= "#1ab2bc ";
                    forma = "P";
                  }else if (data[a][6] == 3){
                   cor= "#9b59b6";
                   forma = "A"
                  }

                }
                
                  this.cores = "#ffffff";
                  
                 
             
                  this.almocos.push(    
                    {
                      id : data[a][0],
                      dia : data[a][1],
                      foto :  data[a][2],
                      foto_anf: this.foto2,
                      estrelas : data[a][3],
                      pessoal : pessoas,
                      tipo : cor,
                      forma :forma,
                      fotos : this.foto,
                      segundo :  this.tempo[2],
                      minuto :  this.tempo[1],
                      horas : this.tempo[0]
                    });

                  
                  

           setInterval(function(){ 
             console.log("segundos");
             let segundos;
             let minutos;
             let hora;

             segundos--;

              if (segundos == 0){
              segundos = 60;
               minutos--;
               
              }
              if (minutos == 0){
              minutos = 59;
                hora--;
              } 
              segundos-- ;
              this.tempos = [];
             this.tempos.push(segundos);
            }, 1000);

            
           
              }
               
              
        
            }, error =>{
              console.log("erro")
            });
//----------------------------------------------------------------------FIM LISTAGEM ALMOÇOS--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  }
```

```html
 <div style="float:right;position:relative;left:0px;position:relative;top:3px">
                            <span><ion-icon style="font-size:14px;" name="md-time"></ion-icon><span style="font-size:13px;position:relative;bottom:1px;margin-left:2px"> {{almoco.horas}}{{almoco.minuto}}{{almoco.segundo}} </span></span>

            </div>
```

The variables are hours, minutes and seconds. Each is related to a date in the database, where we get the time remaining. I'd like to be able to show in real-time a countdown until the actual date.

I know it's possible via Observable, but I can't figure out how. An answer with integer variables (e.g. hours= 23; minutes=14; seconds=19) would be ideal, so I can just attribute the values from the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post some code snippets of your code and what you already tried? What exactly do you get from your db?

Comment: @AndreasGassmann Will do. I've tried using a simple setInterval for example, but it only updates when you enter the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed some issues in your code that could help you to solve your problem:

1. You should avoid to change the `data` object itself and instead create a copy and work with that. That way you always know what the server responded with and what you changed.
2. You have a lot of "hardcoded" array indexes. If you have control over the backend, you should try to avoid that and instead use an object with named properties. So instead of doing

   ```
   this.push(data[a][4][0][1]);
   ```

   you could do something like

   ```
   data[a].almoco.photoUrl // Depending on what you want to do, obviously
   ```

   which looks a lot nicer and gives you more readable code.

Now to your countdown problem:

First of all, you have your `setInterval` inside your for loop, which means that the setInterval is called multiple times per second. (At least as many times as you have elements in your array).

You also define

```
let segundos;
let minutos;
let hora;
```

but never assign them a value, so your if-checks will always be wrong.

You should also avoid calculating the time when you get the response from the server and instead store the end-time you get from the server as a javascript date.

Once you have that, you can either calculate the difference manually in your `setInterval` (end-date - current date, make sure you call it only once) and use a custom angular pipe to convert the seconds to a nice format, or use an npm nodule like this: https://github.com/previousdeveloper/angular2-simple-countdown

Comment: Excellent answer! Not only it fixed the issue, but it's way cleaner and fast. Thank you so much!